# How to restart code if input entered = 'y'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a Python software to encrypt/decrypt/brute force messages, but I need to know how to restart the code at the end, so like at the end it will ask you "Would you like to continue? y/n" If the input is y, restart the code (thats what I need help with), and if the input is n, `break`. I have tried multiple things that don't work. All help is appreciated,

Phineas

(If that is hard to understand, here is what I want to do: at the end of the code, it will ask the users if they want to continue using the program or quit, and if they quit then it will `break`, and if they wanna continue, it will go to the beginning of the code again and start over.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "restart code".

Comment: If you don't show us some example code, we can't show you how to change that code to do what you want.

Comment: did you try infinite loop?

Comment: Please show what you tried; much easier to help you that way.

Comment: @l19 Like, when they've finished doing an encryption or whatever, then it goes to the beginning of the code again and asks them I they want to brute force, decrypt, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your post is not super clear, but here's what I think you want:

```
def main():
    # your brute force code goes here

def run():
    answer = 'y'
    while answer == 'y':
        main()
        answer = input("Would you like to continue (y/n): ")
```

Comment: lol I was just gonna tell him to put `os.system("python %"__file__)` at the end of his program ... but I guess that probably wouldnt have helped him at all in the long run ... +1 for being nicer than me

Comment: @JoranBeasley: lol! And that's a solution I wouldn't have immediately thought of. +1 for creativity

Comment: Yes, but the things is, I already have 3 def functions.

Comment: @Phineas_0510: how does that matter here?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget you can't have a def in a def...

Comment: @Phineas_0510: first of all, yes you can. Secondly, why not define your functions outside, and call them from inside `main`?